# Cannot detect wifi

Tags: wi-fi, tablet, samsung

my Samsung galaxy tab 2 (7.0) cannot detect my home WiFi. but neighbors WiFi can be detected. please help me. but all my phones and laptops can detect my home WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the channel that the wireless is hosted on. I've had this recently with two different devices (one android) where my wireless did not appear in list of available SSID's. In both cases it was in the 5 GHz spectrum and moving my N to a different channel fixed the problem. Apparently certain driver don't implement the full spectrum properly.

Comment: It's not always a driver problem: not all channels are legal to use in some countries, so devices specific to your region will know which channels are legal and only use those channels. Devices from different regions will have different restrictions.

Comment: Good point! I was assuming all devices were from the same region, but I guess a number of my devices have modified firmware so I might just be finding the hard edges.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should contact your home wifi broadband for assistance.If you already did this,I think the problem is in your own tablet